# Where can I find out who the mods of a site are?

Tags: support, moderators

It used to be that when I went to `/about` I would see a list of that site's moderators at the bottom of the page. However, following all the redesigns, that information is no longer listed there. This information is also not listed in:

- the FAQ
- the Help section
- in the meta

Technically, there's a (often long-buried) thread in meta listing pro-tem moderators. But for a site that's graduated with, oh, 17 moderators, that thread isn't relevant. I also know that StackExchange.com has a big list of mods, but why would i go there if I spend all my time on SciFi?

I know I can go to `/users` and look for users with a diamond next to their names, but on sites like Fitness or The Workplace, the mods and top users per week/month/all-time don't necessarily map 1:1 to moderators. Plus, on SO and meta, top users can include employees, who also have diamonds. (This is true on The Workplace -- Oded is a top user there, has a diamond, but he's a SE dev -- something I found out only by clicking through to his profile.)

**Where can I find out who the mods of a site are?** Am I missing a page on the individual sites that indicates who these users are? Or am I stuck clicking through pages of users to find diamonds?

Comment: There's a tab for moderators in the /users page. ([here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) for ex.)

Comment: @Mat Take a screencap and that's an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the comprehensive list in this link:

https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators

For specific site: https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

that is `site/users?tab=moderators`

> [image]

Comment: I acknowledged this list in my post; I was asking for a listing on the sites themselves.

Comment: Ah, ok, you can find the specific one for a site in http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators for example

Comment: Add a screencap and I'll accept this. Thanks!

Comment: Like this one? Should be enough.

Comment: Needs more freehand circles. :P Joking -- I'll accept when it lets me. In 5 minutes. :/